# Angular strict spell search

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

How can I search names starting from first letter that user types, I want to know if user types B then names starting from B must be displayed rather than "SBI" word where B  comes in second position. I want to search specific words which has first word match.

```
for example: if
```

list ={SBI,
      BSI,
      isb,
      bsisib,
      be happy,
      dont worry,
      hello}

Then If i type h character then I want all the words starting from 'h'. but when i tried it shows 'be happy' 'hello' result for h. I want hello only. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're list isn't extremely long try applying a regular expression on each item in ng-repeat filter.

Not sure if you want first word or first character in each word.
Try the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/0UdxjYjzwmOLJNQQlglS).

Comment: sorry i mean first character..In ur list you can see by typing 'h' character it shows "be happy" first then hello. I want to display hello only when user types h. Now you got me? I want character specific search you can say strict to first letter. can you do this for me?

Comment: ok, you can just change return value on the filter function. I updated plunker.

Comment: Well Thats what I was expecting... Thanks:-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this on input field, then
I suggest you to use an existing autocomplete solution for angularjs. There are many of them out there and are quite easy to use.

1. http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete

   Plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/il2J8qOI2Dr7Ik1KHRm8?p=preview
2. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

   Check the typeahead from angular ui bootstrap.

Or just google angularjs autocomplete, you will find tons of results.

Comment: Well @jaanus nice suggestion, but I want using filters. Is that angulars behavior to show all results rather than showing character specific? Any how I marked useful answer but I want that result using filter. can you please explain me why this behavior? n thanks hope autocomplete i can use somewhere in my project. :-)